# How to change FontFamily of Window form?

Tags: wpf, fonts, font-family

I cannot change fontfamily or fontstyle for title of Window Form even though I have already set these properties.The default fontfamily is MS UI Gothic and I want change to meiryo.At XML file, It seems ok but It doesnt have any changes at runtime.

```
 <Window x:Class="TestFont.Window1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Title="Window1" Height="130" Width="369" FontFamily="meiryo"  FontStyle="Italic">
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The window caption is part of the *non-client* area of the window is not really rendered by WPF. The only way you can change that font is by modifying your display properties (a Windows-wide setting).

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the look of the title text. It's decided by theme used, personal settings etc. so it's different on every computer according to the users liking.